# Is there any solve to communicate Parent React Router and Child React router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

child app's router doesn't work.

I'm going to combine 4 separate react apps into a app.
So I generate a create-react-app(parent app) and locate 4 react apps into parent app's src.

App.js in the parent src uses `BrowserRouter` that connect to the children CRA.

The child CRA is also using the router to move to the appropriate url.

app.js in parent src.

```
function App() {
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
  <React.Fragment>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={ReactView}/>
      <Route exact path="/app1" component={ChildApp1}/>
      <Route exact path="/app2" component={ChildApp2}/>
      <Route exact path="/app3" component={ChildApp3}/>
      <Route exact path="/account" component={Account}/>
    </Switch>
  </React.Fragment>
</BrowserRouter>)}
```

ReactView is CRA's default view element.
ChildApp1,2,3,Account is imported well.

`localhost:3000/`
`localhost:3000/app1`, `app2`, `app3` and `/account` is working.

ChildApp1,ChildApp2, ChildApp3 and Account have `BrowserRouter` each.

`localhost:3000/app1/path1` isn't working..

no error messages and no element in the root element. (empty)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an exact prop on the topmost route, no nested routes would match. The solution is to use just switch and order your routes such that the prefix route paths are later in the order

```
function App() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <React.Fragment>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/app1" component={ChildApp1}/>
              <Route path="/app2" component={ChildApp2}/>
              <Route path="/app3" component={ChildApp3}/>
              <Route path="/account" component={Account}/>
              <Route path="/" component={ReactView}/>
            </Switch>
          </React.Fragment>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Comment: yes i should remove exact and path="/" to be last. thanks a lot :)